# Sandbox GameCenter accounts failing to find each other in matchmaking

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm developing a turn-based iPhone game using Game Center. I created two Game Center accounts for testing but neither can find the other when I try to matchmake games. Both are in two matchmade games alone - neither found the other when matchmaking, in spite of the fact that the matches have 8 players max. What do you think could be causing this? Should I just put it on my physical device, because the games don't really work in sandbox, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Gamecenter testing was a big disappointment for me, but I would enjoy to summarize some things that I learned in the process.

Make sure

-You enabled gamecenter support in both **itunes connect**'s app information section and inside version details

-You completed a turn with a call to `endTurnWithMatchData` otherwise no other user will be able to connect to your game

-Know that simulator is able to connect to a game but it can't receive data only actual devices can.

-It is not a lag!

There is the possibility that your devices are actually able to match but there is a huge lag before they can, so you think it is not working. This happens to me with my iPad and iPhone for testing, it always takes around a minute to match another device. I have a asked a question regarding this lag here :[Game Center Matchmaking GKTurnBasedMatch has significant lag (~1 min)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616593/game-center-matchmaking-gkturnbasedmatch-has-significant-lag-1-min) Most replies told same things happens to them and problem is usually in apple's server not your code. I have also contacted apple for the issue by submitting a TSI, they have suggested doing many things (such as trying different gamecenter sandbox accounts, turning off the device, hard reset) but in the end all they told me was 1 min is well within the acceptable lag for turn based matchmaking. I have also submitted a bug report with ID #: **13635249** and its status is open.